# How to access spring API with JWT and x-www-form-urlencoded in angular 2

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, token, jwt

Please someone help me to solve this problem. I have spring controller which can handle every post request which have proper user_name and password. I want to access this in angular 2. Currently if i am accessing this using postman, this work fine, but i still unable to access this by angular 2. this is my spring controller :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> login(@RequestParam String user_name, @RequestParam String password)
           throws IOException {

       String token = null;
       User appUser = useri.findByUserName(user_name);
       Map<String, Object> tokenMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       if (appUser != null && appUser.getUser_password().equals(password)) {
           token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(user_name).claim("roles", appUser.getRoles()).setIssuedAt(new Date())
                   .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "secretkey").compact();
           tokenMap.put("token", token);
           tokenMap.put("user", appUser);
           return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(tokenMap, HttpStatus.OK);
       } else {
           tokenMap.put("token", null);
           return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(tokenMap, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
       }
   }
```

this is the printscreen of my postman request result :

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTnId.png)

I had tried such this code in angular 2 but failed :

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8090/login', JSON.stringify({ user_name: username, password: password }))
        .map((response: Response) => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
            if (token) {
                // set token property
                this.token = token;

                // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ user_name: username, token: token }));

                // return true to indicate successful login
                return true;
            } else {
                // return false to indicate failed login
                return false;
            }
        });
```

request seems doesn't return a response.
Please give me solution, any help will be highly respected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import [URLSearchParams](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html) from [@angular/http](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html)

```
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
```

and use

```
let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
urlSearchParams.append('user_name', username);
urlSearchParams.append('password', password);
let body = urlSearchParams.toString()
```

Comment: i do not know how, but when i run it in browser, it said http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js/src/url_search_params 404 (Not Found), i checked in that path and i found that file...

Comment: If you could give me the following may help resolve that.

Version of Angular2?
Build system?
Angular-Cli?

Comment: "@angular/common": "~2.2.1", i think my angular version 2.2.1, i got it in my package.json. "systemjs": "0.19.40", and this is not cli version

Comment: Is your SystemJS config like the following https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/3b7452cc444c49c139ea39523ced0468c2362c16/systemjs.config.js#L17-L34

Comment: You first need to make sure that requests are forwarded properly. In webpack this would be setting a proxy. I don't know systemjs since it is not very good for Angular2 imo.

Comment: i run npm install one more time and everything run properly. thanks all...